# “no sooner A than B” is a fixed expression but can ‘when’ be interchangeable with ‘than’?

Tags: idioms, comparative-constructions

The following sentence is from *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20sooner)*

> I **had no sooner** walked through the door **when** the phone rang.

As I know, 'no sooner' goes with 'than', though 'scarcely/hardly' goes with 'when'

Is the sentence above ungrammatical?

source: https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/44e9a5317b7942f08f61fd1e019f21fa

Comment: _Is the sentence above grammatically wrong?_ Yes, it is, but this kind of thing is a common mistake in informal speech. The speaker has 'changed direction' in mid-sentence from "I had no sooner... than" to "I had just... when".

Comment: @KateBunting Did you mean 'changed' as a past participle for present perfect or as an adjective modifying 'direction'?

Comment: I meant it as a verb! They presumably started to say "I had no sooner walked [in] than the phone rang", but ended the sentence as though they had started "I had just walked [in] when the phone rang." (It seems like an error to me, but Merriam-Webster evidently find it OK!)

Comment: @KateBunting In TOEFL test, it's absolutely wrong.